# Combobox Search, Second String, Search between the lines VBA

Tags: string, vba, search, combobox

at the moment I am working on a database with a Userform in VBA. The Userform has one Combobox that loads the data from a sheet. The values of the sheet will change, that is why I created it dynamically.

The problem is, that the combobox is pretty long. For example, if I want to search for "combustion engine", I will type in "comb" and it shows me the whole input. So far, this works perfectly. But you always need to know the beginnung of the cell value.
When I type just "engine" there won't be a match, cause no other entry starts with engine. I only have one colomn of data, so is there any solution to show e.g. "combustion engine" only by the input engine?
Thats only a simple example. The list of data includes a lot of cells which contain more than one word.

Does anyone know a solution for my problem? I would be so grateful!
Thank you in advance,
Sophie

Answer (score 0):

assuming combobox is named after "ComboBox1", you may try the following code into the userform code pane

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    Static found As Boolean '<--| this will be used as this sub "footprint" and avoid its recursive and useless calls 

    If found Then '<-- we're here just after the text update made by the sub itself, so we must do nothing but erase our "footprint" and have this sub run at the next user combobox change
        found = False '<--| erase our "footprint"
        Exit Sub '<--| exit sub
    End If

    With Me.ComboBox1 '<--| reference userform combobox
        If .Text = "" Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no text has been typed in
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 '<--|loop through its list
            If InStr(.List(i), .Text) > 0 Then '<--| if current list value contains typed in text...
                found = True '<--| leave our "footprint"
                .Text = .List(i) '<--| change text to the current list value. this will trigger this sub again but our "footprint" will make it exit 
                Exit For '<--| exit loop
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SophieUt, did you get through it?

Comment: @SophieUt, it'd be nice of you to give proper feedback to people trying helping you

Comment: hi @user3598756 - I need your help with your code so it works fine  when I search for a value within a string( dog, cat, rabbit) so if I am searching for cat it will populate the whole line which is needed. But when I try to search for rabbit in the combo box user forum it doesn't populate the whole line unless I press space in front of cat to populate whole line can you help me.